# Any webhook or way to get notification if somebody sends message to Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get a notification when somebody messages my Facebook Page (business). Is there any way to do this?

I see some webhooks Facebook supports at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks but I don't see one that looks that I can use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "conversations" object may be what you want. You can either use webhooks with that object (preferred way) or you can use a cron job to check for new conversations once in a while.